# How to redirect to admin page with custom admin table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

Instead of the laravel multi auth I am using my own (primitive) method to have admin users.

I just have an extra table in the database called `PAdmin` and in this table I have the id's of the admin users.

When I log in to the application I want to redirect the admin users to another page instead of the `home` page.

For that reason, I went to Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated and changed the code so from this :

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{

  if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
  return redirect('/home');

 }

 return $next($request);


}
```

I changed it to this :

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{

    $user_id = Auth::id();


    $isAdmin = PAdmin::where('user_id',$user_id)->get()->isEmpty();//returns 'true' if empty

    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && $isAdmin) {//IF $isAdmin is TRUE it means that the user is not admin

        return redirect('/home');
    }elseif (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && !($isAdmin)){//IF $isAdmin is FALSE it means that the user is not admin

        return redirect('/admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

The idea is simple - if there is a record with the user's ID in the `PAdmin` table `$isAdmin` will be false and the `elseif` will execute.

Unfortunately this isn't working and I don't know why.

Maybe this isn't the right way to do it at all.

Can someone help me get this right.

P.S. I don't want to use `multi auth`.

Comment: Check your ->get() data first.

Comment: You should really change this "if $isAdmin is TRUE it means that the user is not admin"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{

  if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
     if(PAdmin::where('user_id',Auth::id())->first() != null) return redirect('/admin');
     return redirect('/home');

 }

 return $next($request);


}
```

More clear and easier.